# How do i update an array within a cookie?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm saving a cart array within a cookie, to send it to the shopping cart page. Whenever i go to a page from another product and click on add to cart it doesn't add it to the array, but seems to overwrite it.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pin = explode('/', $uri);
$id = $pin[3]; 

$product = $model->selectById($id, 'carpet');
$product = $product->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$site_url = site_url();
if(!$product){
    header("Location: $site_url./404");
}

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $cart = [];
    $cart[$product['id']] = [];
    $cart[$product['id']]['product_name'] = $product['name'];

    setcookie('cart', serialize($cart), time()+3600);
    $cart = unserialize($_COOKIE['cart']);
     dd($cart);
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, because that's what you're telling it to do. You define `$cart` to be an empty array, then add the product to that empty array and overwrite whatever's in the cookie. You need to *retrieve* the array from the cookie and add the product to *that* array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the answer already: you are overwriting the cart each time this script runs. Changes:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pin = explode('/', $uri);
$id = $pin[3]; 

$product = $model->selectById($id, 'carpet');
$product = $product->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$site_url = site_url();
if(!$product){
    header("Location: $site_url./404");
}

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    if ( isset($_COOKIE['cart']) )
         $cart = unserialize($_COOKIE['cart']); // if cookie is set, get the contents of it
    else 
         $cart = []; // else create an empty cart

    // append new product and add to cart
    $cart[$product['id']] = [];
    $cart[$product['id']]['product_name'] = $product['name'];

    setcookie('cart', serialize($cart), time()+3600);
    $cart = unserialize($_COOKIE['cart']);
     dd($cart);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It only works whenever i refresh the page after adding something to the cart array right?

Comment: Is it true, that whenever i want to add the same product into the cart again, that it doesn't add it to the array, but overlapses it?

Comment: Yes,  as you ar taking the unique product ID as index. If you want multiple entires of the same product, the logic needs to be changed. Please be aware, that cookies have a limited size and best pratice is to store shopping cart contents in the session and not in a cookie.

Comment: Hmm, the product id needs to stay the same, let's just say you add 1 sync to the shopping cart, but you want to add 5 more of the same later, it should not be 5 but 6

Comment: Are you willing to use skype chat, for some more questions about cookies, and how to work properly with them?

Comment: @JornReed Sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

2nd part of the question: How to increase order quantity of a product:

```
    ...
    // is this product alread in cart?
    if ( isset($cart[$product['id']])
         $prod = $cart[$product['id']]; // then pick it
    else
    {
         // create a new product object
         $prod = new stdClass();
         // initialze with name and zer quantity
         $prod->name = $product['name'];
         $prod->quantity = 0;
    }

    // increment quantity
    $prod->quantity ++;

    // reassign to array
    $cart[$product['id']] = $prod;

    ...
```

Comment: Do i need to implement that code underneath the part where i set the cookie?

Comment: obviously before!